# Why dynamic_case a references will generate copy-construct function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try dynamic cast a root object reference cast to sub class object reference. I think there is very normal logic. But unexpectedly subclass copy-constract function has be call. in macosx platform sameness test case execute correct.
Why! I think know reason. may be is a bug of the visual studio 2015.

```
class IObject
{
public:
    IObject()
    {}
    IObject(const IObject &ins)
    {

    }
    virtual ~IObject()
    {}
};

class CObject : public IObject
{
public:
    CObject()
    {}
    CObject(const CObject &ins)
    {
        std::cout << "CObject copy constract function has be call" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~CObject()
    {}
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CObject *pCObject= new CObject();

    IObject *pIObject = pCObject;

    CObject &objectRef = dynamic_cast<CObject*>(pIObject) == NULL ? throw  std::exception() : dynamic_cast<CObject&>(*pIObject);

    return 0;
}
```

as below is my test environment and result.

test environment : visual studio 2015, windows 10 64bit
program language : C++ 
test result : the CObject copy constract function has be call.

test environment : Xcode 7, Macosx 
program language : C++ 
test result : the CObject copy constract function not be call.

Comment: Do you know what line the copy constructor is being called on?

Comment: @Nicol: I think the ternary is evaluating to an rvalue, which the reference binds to by creating a temporary (MSVC behavior, in violation of the standard)

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's a long-standing thing, which the VS2015 warns about (at least, on a reasonable warning level). My concern is that, if the expression evaluates to an rvalue, then the compiler should fail with an error. That's the standard behavior, right? So something else is going on here. Plus, what exactly is the result of a throw expression? Because that type is supposed to be what the result of the ternary expression should be, right? It's really unclear whether this code is standard-legal or not.

Comment: @Nicol: I found the controlling rule, quoted in my answer.

Comment: @Nicol: BTW what error would you expect compilation to fail with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that this simple line

```
CObject &objectRef = dynamic_cast<CObject&>(*pIObject);
```

already does the runtime check you are writing, and throws a `bad_cast_exception` if it fails.

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Your code is standard-compliant, it appears that MSVC doesn't correctly implement this rule from section 5.16:

> If either the second or the third operand has type void, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - **The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression (5.17); the result is of the type and value category of the other.** The conditional-expression is a bit-field if
>     that operand is a bit-field.
> - Both the second and the third operands have type void; the result is of type void and is a prvalue. [ Note: This includes the case where both operands are throw-expressions. — end note ]

Because MSVC isn't preserving the value category of the other operand, it is copying it to a temporary.

Another workaround is

```
if (dynamic_cast<CObject*>(pIObject) == NULL) throw  std::exception();
CObject &objectRef = dynamic_cast<CObject&>(*pIObject);
```